# how do I network 3 vps computers together but only have 1 computer is seen on the internet

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I will have 3 vps Windows 2008R2 servers running on hyper-v.

- VPS 1 - data computer - what do I put for the ip?
- VPS 2 - sql server - what do I put for the ip?
- VPS 3 - rdp computer - static ip

I'd like to have the rdp computer the only computer seen on the internet but be able to see the other two computers from the rdp machine. I have a public and the rpd machine is on the internet now and I'm installing the other two. I fear I'll end up with the other two on the internet and prone to attacks.

I don't have the ability for a hardware firewall unless I fork out some major money with our hosting provider so I was hoping there was a networking trick that I could use.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install two network interfaces on the RDP system, set one interface to have a internal IP (like 192.168.1.1) and the external interface to have the IP of you external network.
- On the other two systems set their network interface IP to be on the same network as the internal interface on the RDP server (like 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.1.101)
- In Hyper-V bind the the internal interfaces to a internal network ([See this for help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816585%28v=WS.10%29.aspx))

Comment: that's what I was looking for! ty!

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Windows Firewall (on all three systems).

- On the RDP server, allow connections from anywhere to the RDP port
- On the other two systems, only allow connections from the IP address of the RDP server
- on the DB and data systems, make sure to allow any other traffic required by your application, but only **from** the systems you expect that traffic to come from

Comment: what do I make the ip of the 2 non static ip servers? I don't have a static ip for all 3 computers.

Comment: Well, I guess that depends on how your provider's network is set up. You'll need to talk with them.